# iPhone iOS how to implement a sequence of background network send operations in the fastest way possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, multithreading, networking

I'm trying to stream data to a server at regular intervals and do so in a way that is fast and does not block the UI. The UI is also pretty busy trying to display the data. Currently my implementation uses NSTimer that fires every 50ms, picks a network packet out of a circular array and sends it over:

```
//this is the timer

     networkWriteTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(sendActivity:)  userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


    -(void)sendActivityInBackground:(id)sender
    {
         [[AppConfig getInstance].activeRemoteRoom.connection sendNetworkPacket:[circularArray objectAtIndex:arrayIndex%arrayCapacity]];
    }


    -(void)sendActivity:(NSTimer*)timer
    {

        // Send it out
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(sendActivityInBackground:) withObject:nil];

    }
```

I'm not satisfied with the performance of this method. Time profiling has revealed that there's overhead associated with performing background selectors, and the performance can get quite choppy.

I'm thinking of additional ways to improve performance:

- Improve the performance of the current timer based code
- Try grand central dispatch
- Implement NSOperationsQueue with a single operation.
- Use a dedicated thread that wakes up, checks for update and sends it over if needed

Ideally, I would send data at even faster intervals (10ms or even for each activity update). This poses the question: **What is the fastest way to implement a sequence of background send requests, where order matters?** I want to make sure that one packet gets send before the next one is being sent.

Comment: Apple has their money on GCD. NSOperationQueue maybe a little easier to implement. IT depends on how much time you want to spend

Comment: GCD is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try a recurring dispatch timer (that is part of gcd):

```
self.synchronizerQueue = dispatch_queue_create("synchronizer queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
self.synchronizeTimer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, self.synchronizerQueue);
dispatch_source_set_timer(self.synchronizeTimer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_MSEC * 10, NSEC_PER_MSEC * 1);
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(self.synchronizeTimer, ^
{
   // do your processing here
});
dispatch_resume(self.synchronizeTimer);
```